# Auto Change WooCommerce order status after 1 minute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to auto Change Status of Order from Shipped (custom status i am using) to Completed but after 1 minute Can it be done?

thank

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [WP cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/) (for your case, [once](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/)):

```
function finish_order_status($order_id){
    // your logic here
}

// custom hook listener
add_action('order_status_shipped', 'finish_order_status', 10, 1);

// You will call this when you set your custom status
wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 60, 'order_status_shipped', [$current_order_id]);
```

Comment: thanks for the advice
But I have no knowledge of WP Cron.
Is there a way to create a php file with crontab in direct admin?

Comment: WP Cron doesn't use crontab, it is just it's name. It works different, and the code above explains exactly you need to do. The only issue is, the order will uodate only in the first request received after 1 minute. You can configure your server cron to execute WP cron every minute to get an better timing. Please see the links i've posted with the answer